# Can we use tvs and mov together for thruster?

Tags: power-electronics, safety, surge-protection, tvs, varistor

I want to know if we can use both tvs and mov varistor together ?

What will be good for thrusters ? 
And placement between esc and thruster or before esc?

Update:

system voltage is power supply 48 volt then 2 buck converters then arduino and thrusters ( motor with propeller ) . I wanna protect arduino , converters from surge current and clamp voltages

Comment: These are probably not what you want for that.  What is the system voltage?  What are you trying to protect against?

Comment: Lowest capacitance clamp device draws the least normal current for I=CdV/dt. Then lowest incremental resistance results is best clamp.

Comment: Why would you want to use them together? What is a thruster? What is an esc?

Comment: @Andy aka  thruster is a motor with propeller where thrust force is generated used in quadcopters and rov .  Esc is electronic speed controller used with thruster .  I wanna clamp high voltage for less time and low voltage for long time so thats work of tvs and varistor

Comment: @Chris Stratton system voltage is power supply 48 volt then 2 buck converters then arduino and thrusters ( motor with propeller ) . I wanna protect arduino , converters from surge current and clamp voltages

Comment: *I wanna clamp high voltage for less time and low voltage for long time so thats work of tvs and varistor* - be clear about this. Define precisely what you want.

Comment: @Tony Stewart actually i didnt understand can u make it simpler

Comment: @Andy aka  well , system voltage is power supply 48 volt then 2 buck converters then arduino and thrusters ( motor with propeller ) . I wanna protect arduino , converters from surge current and clamp voltages,iwanna take the advantages of both tvs and varistor

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. The use of an MOV and TVS together is debatable hence, without details of what you propose and without reasons why you think TVS/MOV might work, I can't help.

Comment: @Andy aka actually im still learning about safety so sorry for unintentional being clear. Well motors of thrusters makes surge current , varistor(sorry edited it was tvs wrong) can protect circuit from surge but not continuous surge current

Comment: @andy aka so if surge current is continous i have to  use  tvs , if its not varistor are good solution. Thats as far as i learned not sure about this .

Comment: @andy aka  also varistor will be good for esd ,and tvs for continous surge current .

Comment: Neither are good for continuous surge current. You might consider using a GDT (gas discharge tube) because it clamps down to a small voltage and can dissipate surge energy for a much longer period. GDTs and TVS are used together because GDTs are slow and TVS eats the initial edge of the surge.

Comment: @andy aka i think GDT is not available in my country but i will search again .  Look please here i came across this

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/396475/237957.  Someone ask same question like me so what do u think

Comment: @Andy aka its like what u said that tvs used fkr eating initial surge current .

Comment: I saw that question when it appeared and I backed away from answering because the application to which the circuit was supposedly employed was unclear. Also, an MOV will have a response time much quicker than the surge rise time so putting an MOV and a TVS together appears pointless to me.

Comment: @Andy aka  so u are saying that tvs and mov will response at same time?

Comment: For all standard surges that I know of, both will operate in the same period of time (sub 1 nano second).

Comment: @Andy aka  thanks very much u helped me again . I have one more question. Mov have high capacitance how that affects sensors and signal sensitivity